# Необходимость постановки дефиса

Tags: грамотная-речь

Люди обмениваются действительно научно-значимой информацией.

Требуется дефис?

Answer (score 1):

Люди обмениваются действительно **научно значимой информацией.**

Дефис не нужен, ***научно*** — это наречие со значением "с точки зрения науки".

Сравнить: Люди обмениваются **научно-технической** информацией. Это сложное прилагательное: научная техническая — научно-техническая.

**Примечание**: два наречия плохо сочетаются, лучше убрать наречие *действительно.*